# Ddclient setup issue: external IP

Tags: networking, router, dns, dynamic-dns

I'll describe what I have setup as best I can: I've got a raspberry pi setup as an Apache2 web server running ddclient. It's connected to my Xfinity router, which is setup to port forward to the Pi at port 80. I've got a domain registered with Google Domains and ddclient is configured as you'll see in the first screenshot, but since the Pi is behind a router, I have to set it up to contact an IP checking website in order to get an external IP to supply to Google Domains.

For some reason, I get a "network is unreachable" message when running ddclient. The Pi is able to ping other websites, including Google and Facebook successfully - I am not sure what is stopping it from retrieving its external IP from the dynamicdns website. I have tried other IP-check sites as well and had the same result.

Appreciate any help in advance!

[ddclient.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyo9Y.jpg)

[Error when running ddclient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZD4V.png)

Comment: Because the website died long ago anyway?

Comment: are there any IP-check websites that are active? As I said, I've tried others - probably like 5 of them by now.